# How to executing a windows application from php

Tags: php, windows, web-services

i need to open a external application like Microsoft Word application through php.
is this possible to send content to the msword application from browser -> Edit through Msword -> again return to browser with the edited content.

is this possible through web service .

please advice anyone .

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You mean execute the application on the client workstation?  No.  (Imagine a world where any website you visit could execute applications on your computer.)  The website can send the MS Word file to the browser, then it's up to the browser to decide what to do with it.  Which is generally either save it to the disk or open it in an application.

Comment: yes , imagine a user visiting my website . for editing some content user needs to click some EDIT button . when button is clicked i need open msword application in users system -> edit -> and return back to browser .

Comment: Maybe Office online has some APIs you can use?  I suppose it's worth investigating.  But what you're asking is basically what SharePoint has spent years and millions of dollars trying to achieve.  It's not really something that can be thrown together with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible(I've seen it in the past), but it's not easy and will only work for IE users since there are some ActiveXObjects required for it.

maybe this can het you started: http://extremedev.blogspot.nl/2011/04/word-mail-merge-how-to-merge-through.html